# How to create a class atribute that's a matrix in a Python3 Class?

Tags: python-3.x, class, matrix

I was trying to create a Class to represent a grid map that receives the size of the room and than creates a matrix of the desired size, the matrix should be able to be updated after the init, and I should be able to print it on the console, but the way I'm doing I can't print it, but it doesn't show me any indication of why isn't it working. Any help would be appreciated.

The class is written as follows:

```
class Map:
    def __init__(self, size_x, size_y) -> None:
        self._size_x = size_x
        self._size_y = size_y
        self._matrix = [["."] * size_x for _ in range(size_y)]

    @property
    def max_x(self):
        return self._size_x
    
    @property
    def max_y(self):
        return self._size_y
    
    def print_map(self):
        for i in range(self._size_x):
            for j in range(self._size_y):
                print(self._matrix[i][j], end="")
            print()
        return 0
```

But if I try to generate some simple rooms, the print_map function doesn't print anything nor gets any errors:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    map_sizes = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    dungeon = Map(map_sizes[0], map_sizes[1])
    dungeon.print_map
```

Input:
`2 2`
Output:
``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add brackets after print_map -

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    map_sizes = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    dungeon = Map(map_sizes[0], map_sizes[1])
    dungeon.print_map()
```

Comment: It worked, but now I'm wondering, I was doing it another way, and when I did it with print_map(), I got an error saying that the the type "int" wasn't callable, but now it works, how can I know when to use () or not?

Comment: If it is a function (like print_map) you should call it (by putting ()) or it will do nothing. If it's an attribute (like self._size_x) or property (like max_x) - you don't need to put brackets